# How can I copy records between tables only if they are valid according to check constraints in Firebird/Interbase?

Tags: database, firebird, interbase, check-constraints

I want to copy a bunch of records from a temp table to a target table. The problem is that some records may violate check constraints in the target table so I want to insert everything that is possible and generate error logs somewhere else for the invalid records.

If I execute:

```
INSERT INTO target_table
  SELECT ... FROM temp_table
```

nothing would be inserted if any record violates any constraint. I could make a loop and manually insert one by one, but I think the performance would be lower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
INSERT INTO
    some_table1 (fld1, fld2, fld3)
SELECT
    some_table2.fld1,
    some_table2.fld2,
    some_table2.fld3
FROM
    some_table2
WHERE
    some_table2.fld > 100
LIMIT
    5;
```

Answer (score 7):

You could write an stored procedure which copyes the records and catches any error with `WHEN ANY DO` statement, something like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CopyRecords( ... )
AS
BEGIN
  FOR select ... FROM temp_table INTO ... DO BEGIN
     INSERT INTO target_table ...
     WHEN ANY DO BEGIN
        INSERT INTO ErrorLog(SQL_Code, GDS_Code, ... ) VALUES(SQLCODE, GDSCODE, ...);
     END
  END
END
```

The `WHEN ... DO` statement is documented in [InterBase 6.0 Language Reference](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/reference-manuals/) (scroll down the page, the IB 6 doc downloads are at the bottom), under "Procedures and Triggers" chapter.

The [`GDSCODE`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-gdscode.html) and [`SQLCODE`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-sqlcode.html) context variables should help you to analyse what is exactly the reason of the error.

Comment: Apart from doing an `INSERT ... SELECT .. WHERE <all conditions of the constraints>` I think this is probably the only way.